# How to change the default screen background color of all the pages in React JS(Next JS) using tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, tailwind-css

I am trying to change the default screen background colour of all the pages of the web application.

Technologies I used:

1. React JS
2. Next JS
3. Tailwind CSS

I want to make the screen background colour of all pages light grey as shown in the image instead of the default white colour.

[image]

Is there any way to do that all at once, or do we need to add background colour manually to every page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using NextJS you can make use of a custom file `_app.jsx` (if you are using javascript) or `_app.tsx` (if you are using TypeScript) to change the background colour (and many more by the way) of all your web pages.

You can create a `div` in the file and add background colour to the `className`, it will be applied to all pages being rendered in the web application.

Code example :

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
 return (
  <div className="bg-gray-500">
    <Component {...pageProps}/>
  </div>
 );
}
```

[NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) has a more detailed explanation about this.

Answer (score 5):

Use `@layer base` to customise your html, this is the proper method using Tailwind.

```css
@layer base {
    html {
        @apply bg-gray-50;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can go to styles -> globals.css
and there add the following

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: {color of your choice};
}
```

By this; all your pages will have the specified background color unless you specify a separate background color for any component.

Answer (score 1):

Adding bg-color to a div only adds color to a div... I think the html { background-color: {color of your choice}; is more likely to yield the desired result. Having same issue. Applied your solution but it only filled the div that fell short of page view. Of course the previous comment's coding is incorrect.
should be:

```
html {
    background-color: #yourcolor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In app folder go to file layout.tsx

Just update the Root Layout Component no other changes in that file

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} bg-gray-50`}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```